# Gitlab No repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

Gitlab all of sudden showing no repository message on different repo. I am using docker-compose to run docker ce. I can see on file system on host machine as well as on docker container repository contain data in @hashed folder. I am able to see my ci/cd pipeline and images in container registry. but I am not able to see all my source code in repository. I have try clearing cache and run the gitlab reconfigure command. but not solve the issue.

can anyone know what could be the reason of this kind of behavior.

Comment: What version are you on? Could it be that your instance was exploited? https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cve-2021-22205-how-to-determine-if-a-self-managed-instance-has-been-impacted/60918

Comment: Gitlab version is 12.2.4. Let me check for exploitation, but few of repository I am able to access.